# In jQuery 1.7.2 what is the difference between on("click") and on("click.randomText")?

Tags: jquery, namespaces, jquery-on

I inherited an application which uses jQuery 1.7.2.

Throughout the application we have code like the below:

```
$('#quotation').off("click").on("click", function(){
     // do something here...
}
```

Now, I do understand the above no problem. However, occasionaly in our code I come across something like this:

```
$('#continue').off("click.products").on("click.products", function(){
     // do something here...
}
```

Throughout the application I find `click.products` or `click.orders`. It seems what ever following the `.` can be completly random text.

What is the difference between `click` and `click.products`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code uses custom namespace event defined by them self or by a plugin.

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple" defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are reserved for jQuery's use.

[**`on` docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWD6v/):

```
$('#a').on('click.bar', function() {
    console.log('bar');
});

$('#a').on('click.foo', function() {
    console.log('foo');
});


$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#a').trigger('click.foo');
});​
```

Now when clicking on `#a` both of the clicks handlers (foo and bar) will raise,
But when clicking on `#b` only the foo will raise.

Comment: So, click is not refering to the click event anymore?

Comment: If `click.xxx` is not the `click` event anymore how come the function inside still executes when the control is clicked? It must still be refering to the `click` event somehow?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the documentation by the way. It never dawned on me to check the docs as I had assumed the previous developers had done something custom unrelated to `on()`. I think I get it now. Thanks a lot for your fast answer. (Tried to +1 but can't yet, only at 15 rep, sorry, will come back for it though ones 15 is reached :))

Comment: @Jason. Actually I wasn't right about the trigger. check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sWD6v/) out.

Comment: Nice one on the demo. I think I get it now. Seems that you are able to attach multiple events to the same element separating them out through the use of namespaces. I checked `$("#a").data("events")` and saw multiple click events attached and also a property called `namespace`, which contained the text `bar` for one and `foo` for another `click` event. Thanks again for your help.